# How can I approach analyzing the basic performance characteristics of an unknown aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-performance

I am working on a project for one of my classes. My group and I have been given information on an unknown aircraft, and we must find the max velocity, max R/C, max range, and max endurance of the aircraft at sea level assuming max fuel and payload.

We know its max velocity at an altitude of 21500ft, its wing span, platform area, fuel tank capacity, engine fuel flow rate, payload capacity, empty weight, C(Do) and that its airframe is similar to the A-10 Thunderbolt 2. We are having trouble figuring out how to actually calculate these values. We have been able to calculate it's AR, chord, Oswald efficiency factor, and Reynold's number at altitude, but we don't quite know where to go from here.

We think we might have to calculate the velocity at sea level using the
 $V(alt) = V(SL)\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\rho(SL)}{\rho(alt)}}$ 
formula or that we might have to try and solve for the angle of attach by assuming that L=W at altitude and solving backward from L=q*S*C(L). We are basically lost after this point, though.

If anyone could give us a hint on the correct direction to go from here or let us know if we are approach this problem in the correct way that would be much appreciated! We just need a hint, though, because we want to try and figure out as much of this as we can on our own!

Comment: What you need are the Breguet equations. What data are you missing to evaluate them?

Comment: Please use the search terms "quadratic polar equation" and "Breguet range equation" and read the answers. Let's see how far you get with those. What you are still missing is the engine thrust over speed dependency, so I wonder whether you have more information than you think.